# Moogonse query to update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```json
json:{
data:{
id:"123"}
,
res:{
message:false,
"resId":"afdsfd"
}
}
```

I have to update res in upper json but unable to do so using mongoose in  NodeJS,
my present approach is

```js
model.findOneAndUpdate({"data.id":Id},{res:{message:true,"resId":"eeee"});
```

am I doing something wrong please help me out?

Comment: please share your model

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```js
.findOneAndUpdate({"data.id":Id},{
  "res.message": true,
  "res.resId": "eeee"
})
```